# Detect mouse cursor icon change in application

Tags: vb.net, mouseover

I've been looking for awhile now to no avail for this.

What I'm trying to do is find a way to detect if a mouse icon changes when you mouse over something.

For example: If you mouse over a link it changes from the arrow to a finger.

My plan is to grab the ID of a window, and scan it for clickable objects based on the mouse icon changing. I can grab the window, bring it to the front, and move the mouse around by setting the x,y coord of the mouse, but I don't see a way to detect if the mouse has found anything.

I would prefer this to be something built into vb.net, but if I have to use an API I'm fine with that.

Answer (score 0):

The approach is wrong because the concepts are different from what you observe visually.

There's no such thing as "click" -- there's Button Down event (Windows message sent by the GUI subsystem to the application), Button Up event and Mouse Move event. If there were Button Down and Button Up with no or little Mouse Move, then the OS considers this a click.

All events are sent to the window under the mouse cursor hotspot *unless* the mouse input is captured by the other window.

When the cursor is moved over the window, the OS sends WM_NCHITTEST message to the window to determine, how the window treats the area under the cursor. Based on window's response Windows either performs the window operation (window move or resize etc) or passes mouse-related events to the window procedure. The procedure then decides how to react - do nothing, make visual changes, perform some action etc.

As you can see from the description, cursor change and actual actions are two different loosely related operations. There can be an action without cursor change or cursor change without an action.

Comment: I'm not doing this for some big project or anything where I have to detect every clickable option. This is just something I'm trying to figure out how to do on my own. I understand what you're saying, but this answer doesn't tell me how to detect if the mouse cursor changes....

Comment: @Bigdaddyduergar do you need an answer for the question or solution for the problem? Your question doesn't match your problem.

Comment: I just need to know how to detect when a mouse icon changes.

Comment: @Bigdaddyduergar use Detours library to hook SetCursor WinAPI function.